# Does squaring the elements of the cost matrix change the result of the Hungarian Algorithm?

Tags: optimization, matching-theory

I have a question on the assignment problem, which can be solved with the Hungarian Algorithm.

If we square every element of the cost matrix, would it change the optimal assignment of the Hungarian Algorithm?

I think if we square the elements of the matrix, then the scale of the difference between the elements would be bigger, which can lead to different assignments.